# Android: What is best layout to use when trying to get 2x2 image buttons, and more?

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton, tablelayout

I am trying to make my layout look like so.  I have tried gridviews, table layouts, and more but cant get it to look right. I want something like this.

ImageButton ImageButton2

ImageButton3  ImageButton4

```
    ImageView1
```

ImageButton5  ImageButton6

ImageButton6 ImageButton7 ImageButton8  (these are smaller icons)

```
   ImageButton9 (small donate button)
```

I just cant seem to figure out how to get the layout to work with imagebuttons. What layout should I use? And could you post example code of the xml layout if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this, though there may be another way to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton  android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton  android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton  android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton  android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton  android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center"  android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the result. I threw together an android project and just used the image that is defaulted for the icon.

[image]

Comment: I'll take a look at that but I think the imagebuttons get messed up due to sizing...and wont the linear layout get messed up with different screen sizes/densities?

Comment: You think its possible to center those?

Comment: to center the buttons? just add android:layout_gravity="center" to the linearlayouts for the buttons

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you out:

[**DroidDraw**](http://www.droiddraw.org/) - User Interface (UI) designer/editor for programming with Android

You can use the graphical editor to make your layout, and generate the XML.